# Problem with importing metadata into amundsen

Tags: python, elasticsearch, atlas

i started to learn apache atlas and amundsen and face the problem with importing my metadata from apache atlas into amundsen via elastic search
My code

```
import uuid
import logging

from databuilder.extractor.atlas_search_data_extractor import AtlasSearchDataExtractor
from databuilder.loader.file_system_elasticsearch_json_loader import FSElasticsearchJSONLoader
from databuilder.publisher.elasticsearch_publisher import ElasticsearchPublisher
from databuilder.transformer.base_transformer import NoopTransformer
from databuilder.job.job import DefaultJob
from databuilder.task.task import DefaultTask
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory


def create_es_publisher_sample_job(elasticsearch_index_alias='table_search_index',
                                   elasticsearch_doc_type_key='table'):

    atlas_host = 'localhost'
    atlas_user = 'user'
    atlas_password = 'pass'

    # elastic config
    elastic_host = 'localhost'
    elastic_user = 'user'
    elastic_password = 'pass'
    es = Elasticsearch([
        {'host': elastic_host},
    ],
        http_auth=(elastic_user, elastic_password))

    extracted_search_data_path = '/var/tmp/amundsen/search_data.json'

    task = DefaultTask(loader=FSElasticsearchJSONLoader(),
                       extractor=AtlasSearchDataExtractor(),
                       transformer=NoopTransformer())

    # elastic search client instance
    elasticsearch_client = es
    # unique name of new index in Elasticsearch
    elasticsearch_new_index_key = 'tables' + str(uuid.uuid4())

    job_config = ConfigFactory.from_dict({
        'extractor.atlas_search_data.{}'.format(AtlasSearchDataExtractor.ATLAS_URL_CONFIG_KEY): atlas_host,
        'extractor.atlas_search_data.{}'.format(AtlasSearchDataExtractor.ATLAS_PORT_CONFIG_KEY): 21000,
        'extractor.atlas_search_data.{}'.format(AtlasSearchDataExtractor.ATLAS_VALIDATE_SSL_CONFIG_KEY): True,
        'extractor.atlas_search_data.{}'.format(AtlasSearchDataExtractor.ATLAS_USERNAME_CONFIG_KEY): atlas_user,
        'extractor.atlas_search_data.{}'.format(AtlasSearchDataExtractor.ATLAS_PASSWORD_CONFIG_KEY): atlas_password,
        'extractor.atlas_search_data.{}'.format(AtlasSearchDataExtractor.ENTITY_TYPE_KEY): 'Table',
        'loader.filesystem.elasticsearch.{}'.format(
            FSElasticsearchJSONLoader.FILE_PATH_CONFIG_KEY): extracted_search_data_path,
        'publisher.elasticsearch.{}'.format(ElasticsearchPublisher.FILE_PATH_CONFIG_KEY): extracted_search_data_path,
        'publisher.elasticsearch.{}'.format(ElasticsearchPublisher.FILE_MODE_CONFIG_KEY): 'r',
        'publisher.elasticsearch.{}'.format(
            ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_CLIENT_CONFIG_KEY): elasticsearch_client,
        'publisher.elasticsearch.{}'.format(
            ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_NEW_INDEX_CONFIG_KEY): elasticsearch_new_index_key,
        'publisher.elasticsearch.{}'.format(
            ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_DOC_TYPE_CONFIG_KEY): elasticsearch_doc_type_key,
        'publisher.elasticsearch.{}'.format(
            ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_ALIAS_CONFIG_KEY): elasticsearch_index_alias
    })

    job = DefaultJob(conf=job_config,
                     task=task,
                     publisher=ElasticsearchPublisher())
    return job


def update_index():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    job_es_table = create_es_publisher_sample_job(
        elasticsearch_index_alias='table_search_index',
        elasticsearch_doc_type_key='table')
    job_es_table.launch()


update_index()
```

and its turn me an error

elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [schema : {analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword}}}] [cluster : {analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword}}}] [description : {analyzer=simple, type=text}] [display_name : {type=keyword}] [column_descriptions : {analyzer=simple, type=text}] [programmatic_descriptions : {analyzer=simple, type=text}] [tags : {type=keyword}] [badges : {type=keyword}] [database : {analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword}}}] [total_usage : {type=long}] [name : {analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword}}}] [last_updated_timestamp : {format=epoch_second, type=date}] [unique_usage : {type=long}] [column_names : {analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={normalizer=column_names_normalizer, type=keyword}}}] [key : {type=keyword}]')

my json looks like

{"badges": [],
"cluster": "calster_name",
"column_descriptions": [],
"column_names": ["file_name", "file_date", "content", "version"],
"database": "database_name",
"description": null,
"display_name": "None.raw_data",
"key": "apps_test://test.None/raw_data",
"last_updated_timestamp": 1683808295, "name": "raw_data", "programmatic_descriptions": [], "schema": "None", "schema_description": "", "tags": [], "total_usage": 0, "unique_usage": 0}

i use default mapping ElasticsearchPublisher

```
{
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "normalizer": {
                    "column_names_normalizer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "filter": ["lowercase"]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "schema": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "display_name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "last_updated_timestamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "epoch_second"
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "simple"
                },
                "column_names": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "normalizer": "column_names_normalizer"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "column_descriptions": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "simple"
                },
                "tags": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "badges": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "cluster": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "database": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "key": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "total_usage": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "unique_usage": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "programmatic_descriptions": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "simple"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i dont know even where to start
find nothing about that error in same as mine case
please help
thx